# Find location of Meteor Assets

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a folder on my machine that I am adding files to while my meteor app is running. The path of it is `~/uploads`. I have been able to successfully use the `Assets.getBinary()` from the `private` folder but not a folder outside of my meteor project. How would I use an `Assets.getBinary()` where the location of a file is `~/uploads/foo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to send `Assets.getBinary()` a path that is not a descendent of the private directory. If you must keep assets outside the private directory, say for sharing them between applications, you can symlink the folder inside your private directory.

`cd` into your private directory and run:

```
ln -s ~/uploads uploads
```

then you can reference any assets in your `~/uploads` directory through that path, for example:

```
Assets.getBinary("uploads/foo");
```

Comment: thats what I ended up doing. However every time I write to my private directory my app refreshes. Any way to stop that?

Comment: Yep, delete .meteor\local\build (this will recompile)